# Controlling many instances of the same type

Tags: vb.net, gecko, instances

I recently decided to see what's going on with vb.net and I was intrigued to create a basic web browser for myself.

I added a tabcontrol into my form and inside a gecko component, everything fine so far. I also managed to open a clicked link in new tab (a thing which I thought would be very difficult) but then I realized that the browser (2nd instance) in the new tab didnt "listen" to the this rule.

Here is the code

```
Private Sub Gecko_DomClick(sender As Object, e As DomMouseEventArgs) Handles Gecko.DomClick
    Clicked = Gecko.Document.ActiveElement.GetAttribute("href")
    If Clicked <> "" Then
        Gecko.Navigate(False)
        Dim Gk As New Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add("New Page")
        TabControl1.SelectTab(1)
        Gk.Name = "Web Browser"
        Gk.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Gk)
        CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser).Navigate(Clicked)
    End If
End Sub
```

So my question is, how to write a function in order to control every new instance of the gecko browser?

Comment: its not a rule, its an event handler.  you need to wire your new control to it

Comment: Use the [**AddHandler statement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, looks like it works now.